# How to detect if iAd loaded using an "if" statement

Tags: ios, if-statement, iad

I have a code that creates a button depending whenever a user has an iphone 4 or 5 and whenever they purchased an IAP to remove ads. Below is the code for it:

```
if ((int)[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)
{
    // This is iPhone 5 screen
    if (intvalue == 1) {
        //No Ads
        self.infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoDark];
        self.infoButton.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.infoButton.center = CGPointMake(289, 495);
        [self.view addSubview:self.infoButton];
    }
    else{
        //Yes Ads
        self.infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoDark];
        self.infoButton.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.infoButton.center = CGPointMake(289, 451);
        [self.view addSubview:self.infoButton];
    }

} else {
    // This is iPhone 4/4s screen
    if (intvalue == 1|) {
        //No Ads
        self.infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoDark];
        self.infoButton.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.infoButton.center = CGPointMake(289, 429);
        [self.view addSubview:self.infoButton];
    }
    else{
        //Yes Ads
        self.infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoDark];
        self.infoButton.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.infoButton.center = CGPointMake(289, 400);
        [self.view addSubview:self.infoButton];
    }
}
```

However one issue for me occurs when the ads don't load. The button is still placed higher in the screen that when it should be. How do I detect if ads did not load place the button in the location of when ads are removed?

Comment: Looking at its delegate method: `bannerViewDidLoadAd:`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the ADBannerViewDelegate Protocol in your class.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/Reference/ADBannerViewDelegate_Ref/Reference/Reference.html

When an ad is loaded, Apple will call bannerViewDidLoadAd.

When an ad is not loaded, Apple will call bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError:

So for a temporary fix, in your code I would always draw the button as if an ad did not load. Then when the ad does load (inside bannerViewDidLoadAd) move the button down and display the ad.